# Advanced custom fields not showing repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

Hello so i have had problems showing ACF fields because of an custom plugin.
I did then find out that i can instead write:

```
<?php $outputtext= get_field('text'); ?>
<?php echo $outputtext; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php get_field('text'); ?>
```

because this didn't work when plugin was activated.

So i have been searching for an answer for a while now and been testing the same way i did get fields to also show an repeater to. No success...

And yes i have been testing regular code wich is

```
    <?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('topp_yrken_referenser') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('topp_yrken_referenser') ) : the_row(); { ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
               <blockquote>
                    <?php // display a sub field value
                    the_sub_field('topp_yrke_referens');
                    ?>
               </blockquote>
            </div>


       <?php } endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
    ?>
```

This is how it worked before the custom plugin and stopped to work

1. How do i make something like this work like i made  work with this instead?
2. Is there an name for this **$this**= get_field('text'); ?

Comment: Does it work without the else/endif?

Comment: Without else it's pretty much the same. Without endif i get empty site and without both else and endif i get empty page...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (have_rows('topp_yrken_referenser')){ ?>
     <?php while (have_rows('topp_yrken_referenser')) { the_row(); ?>
     div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
               <blockquote>
                    <?php the_sub_field('topp_yrke_referens'); ?>
               </blockquote>
            </div>
     <?php }; // while:   ?>
    <?php }; ?>
```

This is as barebones as the code can get.